# Qt widget application output to console

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm developing a GUI application based on widget in Ubuntu. I would like to print some debug information to console with `printf`. Is it possible to show console window while debugging application in Qt?

Comment: If you use Qtcreator this should be standard when you run it in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Just run your application in the debugger from a terminal (like `gdb myapp`) or instruct your IDE (whatever it is) to run the program in a terminal - both qtcreator, visual studio and others support this.

Comment: How to tell QT to run application in terminal?

Comment: @vico Qt or no Qt is irrelevant.  step 1) open a terminal window. step 2) navigate to the directory with your application. step) run your application from the terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's easily possible. Since you're working with a Qt Application, I would utilize the Qt debugging module; QDebug. To have the console appear on a GUI application you need to edit the CONFIG parameter in the *.pro file like below:

```
CONFIG += console
```

This will force any Qt Application to also spawn a console along side it, even if started with a desktop shortcut. Finally, instead of using printf(..), I would use qDebug(). It's built into Qt and simplistic to use. In the files you would like to use qDebug, just add:

```
#include <QDebug>
```

When you would like to output a message to the console just write:

```
qDebug() << "This will output to the spawned console!";
```

or,

```
qDebug() << QString("This will output to the spawned console!");
```

Finally, using the qDebug method allow's you to provide classes with debug operators like below:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(..);

        QDebug operator<< (QDebug d, const MyClass &myclass) {
            d << "This is what I want to output to the console!";
            return d;
        }
```

This will allow you to make cleaner code than using fprint(..)
 throughout your project, hope it helps!